# Nodejs how to access SerialPort path on 'data' event

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I am using the SerialPort library in nodejs to list the available ports, and send data to each of them. If any of them return "OK", I would like to find out which is the port that returns it:

```
SerialPort.list().then(ports => {
            ports.forEach(port => {
                    var rtuSocket = new SerialPort(port.path, { baudRate: 9600 }, (err, data) => {
                        rtuSocket.on('data', (err, data) => {
                            console.log(rtuSocket.path)
                            console.log("[RTU][CONNECTED]")
                        })
                        rtuSocket.write("AT")
                    })
            })
        })
```

Obviously the rtuSocket will be a different variable by the time data return. Is there a way to know which port is returning the data inside .on("data") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of timeout to detect if a port is not responding. I also strongly suggest you check the response data and send something more than a simple "AT" command because a lot of other devices respond to AT commands such as RGB controllers for gaming PCs and some Android phones configured as modems.

Something like the following should work:

```
function checkPort (path, callback) { // callback(error, path)
    let sock = new SerialPort(path, { baudRate: 9600 }, (err, data) => {
        let timer = setTimeout(() => {
            callback(new Error('Timeout'));
        }, 100); // 100ms should be enough. If not increase it

        sock.on('data', (err, data) => {
            clearTimeout(timer); // clear the timer

            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            else {
                return callback(null, path);
            }
        })
        sock.write("AT");
    })
}
```

Now you can check which port is connected:

```
function findConnectedPort (callback) {
    SerialPort.list().then(ports => {

        portCount = ports.length;

        ports.forEach(port => {
            checkPort(port.path, (err, foundPath) => {
                if (err) {
                    // Ignore errors or deal with them how you want
                }
                else {
                    // Great! Got response. Return the path:

                    if (portCount > 0) { // prevent calling callback
                                         // more than once
                       
                        callback(null, foundPath);
                    }
                    portCount = 0;
                }

                portCount--;

                if (portCount <= 0) {
                    // Well, none of the ports responded so we
                    // return an error:

                    callback(new Error('Not found'));
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Now to find the connected port simply do:

```
findConnectedPort((err,path) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("RTU CONNECTED at " + path);

        // Do what you need with the port here...
    }
})
```

#### Promises and async/await

While the code above works. For asynchronous code that requires a lot of conditional logic like this I find using async/await much easier to reason about. For that you need to convert your code to return promises:

```
function checkPort (path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let sock = new SerialPort(path, { baudRate: 9600 }, (err, data) => {
            let timer = setTimeout(() => {
                reject(new Error('Timeout'));
            }, 100); // 100ms should be enough. If not increase it

            sock.on('data', (err, data) => {
                clearTimeout(timer); // clear the timer

                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    return resolve(path);
                }
            })
            sock.write("AT");
        })
    });
}
```

Now the for loop is easier to understand albeit now you cannot use `forEach` or `map` or `filter` or any array methods. You need to use `for` or `while` if you want to use async/await:

```
async function findConnectedPort () {
    let ports = await SerialPort.list();

    for (let i=0; i<ports.length; i++) {
        let port = ports[i];

        try {
            // return the first successful result:
            return await checkPort(port.path);
        }
        catch (err) {
            // ignore errors or handle them how you like
            // just remember that we use an error to signal
            // a timeout which simply means no device
            // responded
        }
    }

    // we didn't find anything. In this case I prefer to return
    // nothing instead of returning an error:

    return null;
}
```

Now you can simply get the connected port by doing:

```
async function main () {

    let connectedPath = await findConnectedPort();

    if (connectedPath === null) {
        console.log('No devices found!');
    }
    else {
        // Do what you need with the port here...
    }
}

main();
```